# How to pass arguments to a function?

Tags: c++, function, arguments

I have a problem how to make code more readabel with less local variables and symbols like "*", "&"

When I write something like this:

```
inline std::string&
EmbraceBySQuote (
            std::string& str ) {
    str = "'" + str + "'";
    return str;
}  /* -----  end of function EmbraceBySQuote ----- */
```

I cannot do something like this

```
fmter % ( *detail::EmbraceBySQuote ( &table.GetTableName ( ) ) );
table.GetTableName ( ) //returns std::string
```

I get an error

```
invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ... from a temporary of type rvalue ...
```

The same with pointers

```
inline std::string*
EmbraceBySQuote (
            std::string* str ) {
    *str = "'" + *str + "'";
    return str;
}  /* -----  end of function EmbraceBySQuote ----- */


fmter % ( *detail::EmbraceBySQuote ( &table.GetTableName ( ) ) );

taking address of temporary
```

So I need something like this

```
std::string tableName = table.GetTableName ( );
fmter % ( *detail::EmbraceBySQuote ( &tableName ) );
```

Do you know how to make it more simple without creation of new variable and using reference?

Comment: what's with the formatting? And the end of function comment? Ditch it!

Comment: `fmter % ( *detail::EmbraceBySQuote ( &table.GetTableName ( ) ) );` Ok, i'm gonna regret this, but wth is **that** ??

Answer (score 2):

Your code betrays a lack of understanding of... a lot of things.

For example:

```
&table.GetTableName ( )
```

As you state, `table.GetTableName()` returns a `std::string`. Presumably that's returning a value. That means it's returning a temporary.

So first problem: you cannot take the address of a temporary. So `&table.GetTableName()` is not legal C++ code. You don't need the `&`.

Second problem: even if you *could* take the address of a temporary, `EmbraceBySQuote` does not take a *pointer*. It takes a *reference*. References and pointers are different things. You cannot pass a pointer to a function expecting a reference (unless it's a reference to a pointer).

Third problem: `EmbraceBySQuote` takes its parameter by *non-`const`* reference. A temporary cannot bind to a non-`const` reference. So you cannot pass a temporary to this function.

Fourth problem:

```
*detail::EmbraceBySQuote
```

A reference is not a pointer, so you can't *dereference* it.

You need to stop and go back to intro-to-C++ and start from there. You have some very confused ideas about basic C++ principles of references and pointers. And you need to get that sorted out.

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that `table.GetTableName()` returns a `const std::string&`, or more likely, a `const char*` As a result, the compiler is having to contrive a temporary std::string to pass to `EmbraceBySQuote`, and compiler-contrived temporaries cannot be passed as non-const references (your compiler *may* support it, but it is non-standard if it does).

There are a number of ways you can fix this, one of them listed below:

```
inline std::string EmbraceBySQuote(const char* str)
{
    std::string ans = str;
    ans.insert(ans.begin(), '\'');
    ans.push_back('\'');
    return ans;
}

inline std::string EmbraceBySQuote(const std::string& str)
{
    std::string ans = "'" + str + "'";
    return ans;
}
```

Note: these will NOT modify the in-parameter in-place. You must assign the result yourself if that is what you want.

```
std::string foo = "foo";
foo = EmbraceBySQuote(foo);
```